# Error when using enumerate() in Swift 2.0

Tags: swift

When I attempt to use the enumerate function, I get an error saying:

'enumerate is unavailable, call the 'enumerate()' method on the sequence.

Here is the line of code returning the error:

```
for (idx, diff) in enumerate(blockRowColumnTranslation) {
   blocks[idx].column = column + diff.columnDiff                
   blocks[idx].row = row + diff.rowDiff
}
```

Comment: Try `blockRowColumnTranslation.enumerate()`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer! I receive the same error for the following code:        for (idx, block) in enumerate(shape.blocks) {

Comment: Yep.  Same thing.  `shape.blocks.enumerate()`.  I think you can see the pattern.

Comment: I am also having problems with this:   SKAction.group([moveToAction, SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1.0, duration: 0.2)]), completion: nil) }

Comment: It gives me the error:  Nil is not compatible with expected argument type '0 -> Void'

Comment: You should Google the error you are getting.  If you don't find a duplicate, post a new question to StackOverflow.